Order Type of Totally Ordered Abelian Groups
As a preface, I don't know much group theory, so this might be a trivial question. I looked at some other questions on stack exchange, but I didn't notice a result which answers my question immediately.
I'm taking my first group theory course right now, and one of our assignments was intended to familiarize us with group isomorphisms. We were asked to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not group isomorphic under addition. My solution relied a lot on their order types being different, so I was wondering if that was the "underlying reason" for why they aren't group isomorphic. Written in full, my question is the following:
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are totally ordered sets, and $(X, +_X)$ and $(Y, +_Y)$ are Abelian groups. Additionally, suppose that $+_X$ and $+_Y$ satisfy:
$$a < b \implies a + c < b + c$$
For "$+$" and "$<$" as defined for $X$ and $Y$. If there exists a group isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$, must there also exist an order isomorphism between them?
I feel like it's true, but I got stuck when I tried to prove it. My strategy was:

show that $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$
show that if $B_Y$ is a basis for $Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a group isomorphism, then $f^{-1}(B_Y)$ is a basis for $X$
fix a basis $B_Y$ consisting of positive elements, then construct a group isomorphism $g:X \to Y$ such that $g^{-1}(y) > 0$ for all $y \in B_Y$
Use 3. to show that $\ g(x) > 0 \iff x > 0 \ \ $ when $x \in \{ \sum_{n = 1}^{N} k_n g^{-1}(y_n): \ \, y_n \in B_Y, \ \ N, k_n \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \langle g^{-1}(B_Y) \rangle$.

I'm having trouble proving that $g$ is well-behaved under infinite sums of linearly independent vectors, so I hit a snag when trying to prove 2. Also, 4. only helps me if $B_Y$ generates $Y$, and I'm struggling to extend 4. to infinite sums when $B_Y$ doesn't generate $Y$.
Any tips/help is appreciated!

"Vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$" is not a thing. If you mean that it has a "$\mathbb{Z}$-basis", the term is "free abelian", but then not every ordered abelian group is free; e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis.

Also, "infinite sums" are not a thing.

For the "infinite sums" bit, I was thinking about a space like $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. I wanted to say something to the effect of "$\chi_{\mathbb{R}} = \sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \chi_{{r}}$" -- I wasn't sure what to call that besides an "infinite sum", and I didn't find a way to treat this like some kind of limit for general $Y$.

In a vector space, there are no "infinite sums". Addition is a binary operation, so you can only add finitely many things, never infinitely  many things. The same is true in an abelian group. The set ${\chi_{{r}}\mid r\in\mathbb{R}}$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, because it does not span. Its span is the set of functions of finite support. It is simply not the case that $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}$ can be obtained from the abelian group generated by the $\chi_{{r}}$.

I do see what you're saying, but I'm still a little unclear on why there isn't some nice way to define an "infinite sum". Do we say that $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \chi_{{r}} $ is poorly defined because sets like ${\chi_{{0, r}} : \ r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}}$ have the property that every finite subset is linearly independent, but $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}^+} c_r \chi_{{0, r}}$ for $c_r \in \mathbb{R}$ would behave very poorly at $0$?

The expression you write would not be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ unless the expression $\sum_{r\in\mathbb{R}}c_r$ made sense. This would require that all but finitely many of the $c_r$ be equal to $0$, as otherwise you have an uncountable sum (not even a series!); if infinitely countably many were nonzero you could get a conditionally convergent series, in which case it has not defined value. For some vector spaces you can define a kind of "convergence" (they are called Banach spaces, where your vector space has a notion of "size"), but that isn ot the case for general ones.

And of course, this completely ignores the fact that we aren't even talking about vector spaces, we are talking about abelian groups, where there is even less structure. As a $\mathbb{Z}$-vector space, $\chi_{{r}}$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}$ does span even if you allow "infinite sums"  over pairwise disjoint index families, because you never obtain the function whose value at $0$ is $\pi$.

I think I may have phrased my follow up question improperly. I get that $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}^+} c_r \chi_{{0, r}}$ only makes sense when countably many $c_r$ are non-zero and when $\sum c_r$ converges. I was wondering if the fact that $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}^+} c_r \chi_{{0, r}}$ does not really "make sense" is part of the reason why we don't allow ourselves to play around with objects that look like $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \chi_{{r}}$.
I was hoping that the structure I gave to $X$ and $Y$ was enough, so I didn't want to impose a norm on $X$ or $Y$ to define convergence.

I originally imagined that the "basis of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$" that I was looking for would involve some kind of gross decomposition of $\mathbb{R}$ into sets $S$ where $x - y \in \mathbb{Q} \ \forall , x,y \in S$, or something. Of course, I completely missed that an "infinite sum" over that kind of basis would probably be poorly defined like $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}^+} c_r \chi_{{0, r}}$ is.

First, even if $\sum c_r$ converges, if it is conditional convergence then the value depends on the order in which you add them, so it won't be well defined as there may not be a natural well ordering on the indices. Second, once you allow infinite sums of some vectors (say, your preferred basis), you either allow it for any such family of vectors (which runs into problems), or you only allow it for some familes... which may break all kinds of theorems in linear algebra that allow you or require you to change bases around.

Your conjecture is not true. You can have two totally ordered abelian groups which are isomorphic as groups, but such that there is no order isomorphism between them. I will use the Axiom of Choice to guarantee the existence of a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.
As abelian groups, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic: they are both vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $\mathfrak{c}$. Give $\mathbb{R}$ its usual order. Give $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ the lexicographic order: $(a,b)\lt (x,y)$ if and only if $a\lt x$, or $a=x$ and $b\lt y$. It is straightforward to verify this is a total order that respects addition.
But all sets of the form $\{a\}\times\mathbb{R}$ are order isomorphic to the real line and pairwise disjoint, and there are uncountably many of these. The real line, on the other hand, can only contain countably many such subsets. So the two orderings are not isomorphic.
Alternatively, the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not have the supremum property: the nonempty subset $\{(0,r)\mid r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is bounded above, for example by $(1,0)$, but has no supremum: no point of the form $(x,y)$ with $x\leq 0$ is an upper bound, and no upper bound is the least upper bound, since $(x/2,0)\lt (x,y)$ for any $x\gt0$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and $(x/2,0)$ is an upper bound for the set.

The "real" reason $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ is that the latter is divisible (for any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and positive integer $n$, there exists $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $nr=q$). But $\mathbb{Z}$ is not. In fact, for every $n\gt 0$, $n\mathbb{Z}$ is properly contained in $\mathbb{Z}$.
